# Can a neural network be trained repeatedly on subsets of data to fight overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, overfitting

I've used random forests for years but I'm less experienced building neural networks. Overfitting is obviously a concern for both decision trees and neural networks. Statistically, random forests are much more robust than decision trees. They use subsets of the data (with replacement) and then average the results (there's a lot more going on in random forests, but that'll do for our purposes here). I'm familiar with [MC dropout](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02142.pdf), which applies a random approach for regularizing neural networks.

Here's my question. Why don't neural networks train on multiple subsets of data (with replacement) and then combine their results like random forests? It seems like a good way to fight overfitting but it seems like this isn't a common practice. Is there a mathematical reason that this doesn't work?

Comment: You can easily overfit the random forests with resampling. It's not like RF are inherently resistant to overfitting

Comment: @Aksakal That's a good point. I meant more resistance to overfitting, which RF is compared to decision trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these things can be done. You can combine the predictions of multiple neural networks as an [ensemble estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning), even though the RF approach tends to be the classic estimator because of the thematic congruity between random forests and multiple forests.  You can also [boost neural networks as well](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12368221_Boosting_Neural_Networks).